# Bayes Theorem for Conditional event that is an intersection of independent events.

Tags: conditional-probability

I have a question regarding Bayes theorem, and independent intersected events as the conditional.  How can this probability be decomposed using Bayes?

$P(H \mid E \cap R)$ where $E$ and $H$ are independent events.

Does that equal $P(H\mid E)\cdot P(H\mid R)$?

Comment: No.  Let $R$ also be independent of $H$.  Then you're asking if $P(H)=P(H)\cdot P(H)$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$P(H|E,R) = P(H,E,R)/P(E,R)$

$ P(H,E,R) = P(H|E,R)/P(E,R)$